# Message getting consumed multiple times from Kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I am facing a weird issue while using Kafka. We have a Kafka server setup and are using the Kafka-node client on the backend to consume or produce messages to Kafka topics. The issue is happening when the message is consumed from topics. Sometimes a particular message is consumed only once but sometimes a message is consumed multiple times. The issue happens randomly.

Can anyone please help with this? Also, I am not sure about what else to paste here, do let me know if I need to add some more information for better guidance on this issue.

Nodejs version - 18.2
Kafka-node version - 2.4.1
kafka version - 3.3.1

I have not tried anything yet as I am not aware of where to start looking and how to start troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: your problem could be either the producer is sending some messages multiple times, due to broker instability (check delivery semantic and idempotence configs).
you can double check this, by simply running kafka-console-consumer to read the messages from your topic, this will show is the message actually duplicated from producer side, or no duplication and it is a consumer issue, if a consumer issue, then you need to check the offset committing and consumer status (no rebalances)

Comment: I have commented out the following property "group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0" from the server.properties file but even then the same issue is happening.